# Value of $\sin(A+B)$ when $\sin A=0.6$ and $\sin B=-0.8$

Tags: trigonometry

Without using a calculator, how can I get the value of $\sin(a+b)$ when $\sin A=0.6$ and $\sin B=-0.8$? It is given that
$$\frac{\pi}2<A<\pi$$
$$\pi<B<\frac{3\pi}2$$
and I know
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A$$
but I don't know how can I derive $\cos A$ and $\cos B$ without using calculators.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Use $$\sin^2 A + \cos^2 A = 1$$

If $\frac{\pi}2 < A < \pi$, then $\cos A < 0$.

Similarly for $B$.

Comment: thank you, so so so helpful!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1.$

You have $\sin x$ for $x = A $ and for $x=B,$
so you can use the formula above to find $|\cos A|$ and $|\cos B|$.
Then use the given ranges for $A$ and $B$ to figure out whether
each cosine should be negative or positive.

Comment: thank you, so so so helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You know the formula from pre-calc

$$sin(A+B)= sin(A)cos(B)+ sin(B)cos(A)$$

Substatuting what you know 
$$sin(A+B)= 0.6cos(B)-.8cos(A)$$

Now we are almost done consider if you know $sin(A) $ you know $cos(A)$ as well using $sin^2( A) + cos(A)^2 = 1$ so solving for cosine we get
$$cos(A) = \sqrt{1- (0.6)^2}$$, use the same strategy for the other.